# Constructor with optional parameters and the new()-constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, compiler-errors, optional-parameters

I love optional parameters in C#. But when using them in a constructor, so that the signature looks (or can look) like the default constructor, things get odd when using generics and the `new()`-constraint:

```
class A<T> where T : new() { }

class B : A<B>
{        
    public B(bool b = false) { } 

    // 'B' must be a non-abstract type with a public **parameterless** constructor
    // in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or metho A<T>
}
```

In the example above, the compiler complains, that there is no parameterless constructor, forcing me to add something like: `public B() : this(false) { }` (effectively making the optional version redundant).

Really? I can do `new B()`, so whats wrong with it? (Aren't methods with optional parameters 'expanded' during compilation?) Am I missing a point? I know that asking such questions might lead into answers like "this was a design decision", or "it was easier to implement", but in most cases I'm only overlooking something. :-)

Comment: Not sure what is your question: clearly constructor with optional parameter is *not* constructor without parameters. So are you asking why this decision was made (unlikely to get extended  answer), how to work around it (but you have code sample already in post) or something completely different?

Comment: So what makes a constructor like the one shown above different from one without parameters as long as it _can_ be called without parameters? Maybe I'm lacking the understanding how optional paramters are compiled/interpreted. My question actually is: Is there a deeper meaning for this differentiation? (If there is none, the question is somehow meaningless, of course.)

Comment: Answer that @MarcinJuraszek suggested contains very detailed explanation. Short - `public B(bool b = false)` does not automagically create `public B()` at any point (compile/run time) - so class does not contain parameter-less constructor.

Comment: Ha! Thanks for the link - thats pretty much the answer: The problem is, that optional parameters are a compiler feature and therefore are converted to methods with parameters and attributes (with the default values) for the CLR. And since the generic constraints are the CLR's topic, they cannot be automatically evaluated for this case. (At least as long the CLR does not support optional parameters in the future and then would probably support this construct, too.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by *Aren't methods with optional parameters 'expanded' during compilation?* but I would say no.

Instead of creating another method without optional parameter during compilation every method call without that parameter specified is changed to contain the default value.

So every

```
var b = new B();
```

is during compilation changed to

```
var b = new B(false);
```

and non additional constructor is created for you. Nothing like that:

```
public B() : this(false) {}
```

is added to your code during compilation.

I think that makes it non possible to use type with constructor with optional parameter as generic type when it's set by `new()` constraint.

Comment: Yes, I agree, thanks. But argumenting like this couldn't all the generic calls be substituted as well? `new T()` -> `new T(false)`. But, regarding the other arguments against it, I don't want to take up this position :-).

Comment: But problem is, generics is CLR feature, and it has to work with languages which does not support optional parameters.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, too. So the conclusion is something like: It doesn't work and there are good reasons for it. And for a workaround: Just don't use optional parameters in this case or at least specify an additional parameterless constructor. (Ok, that's pretty straightforward...)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this definition:

```
class B
{
    private readonly bool _z;
    public bool Z { get { return _z; } }

    private readonly int _k;
    public int K { get { return _k; } }


    public B(bool z = false)
    {
        _z = z;
    }
    public B(int k = 1)
    {
        _k = k;
    }
}
```

The compiler would not know which of the constructors to use in your generic class. Of course there are ways to resolve this. One of these is to mandate that the class should have parameterless constructor to be eligible for such usage, exactly as you described.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks! I didn't think of that. So in addition to the aspects postet in Marcin Juraszek's link from above, there are plenty of reasons why this is a problematic case.